# How to send funds from one account to another directly without involving the contract balance using a variable (eg. amount) instead of msg.value

Tags: static, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have been trying a lot (even using chatGPT) but I couldn't find a way to transfer X funds from account A to account B directly without involving the contract. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkxDP.png)

Please Help.

I tried sending x amount of funds to account B specified by the function's arguments directly without involving the contract's balance. I was expecting the account B to receive the x amount of funds from my account directly.

Comment: are you sending `erc20` token

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your question is that you want to send some ETH from your EOA to another EOA or any contract using smart contract.

If that's what you are looking for it then you can use it

```js
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract PAY {
    function sendEther(address payable receiver, uint256 amount) external payable {
        uint val = msg.value;
        require(val >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        (bool success, ) = receiver.call{value: val}("");
        // receiver.transfer(val);
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
}
```

- You have to use `msg.value` for this.

But to use this you have to send the whatever ether you want to send during method call using

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3SF.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdDGr.png)

Be careful about proper unit of ether, if you are sending the value in amount of ether then choice ether unit and pass the proper `value * 1e18` in function parameter as above two images.

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMLmS.png)

As you can see I've 101 faucets in my seconds account after successful transaction it will increase to 102.

[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DRUI.png)

Apologies for image as I lack the reputations to post image.

Let's Assume a scenario that `person A` wants to send `person B` `1 ether` using smart contract.

Now using above smart contract `person A` calls `sendEther` method from smart contract. what he has to do is that during method call he has to pass receiver address in this case `person B` address and amount to send in parameters. In this case is image 2 which I shared above. Be careful if you want to send the 1 ether you have to pass `1 * 10**18 = 1000000000000000000` reason is it will consider the smallest ether unit wei and `1 ether = 1 * 10 ** 18`.

But Now let's assume we don't have fund in this smart contract or we don't want to use the smart contract fund, in that case what person A has to do is during `sendEther` method call he has to send 1 ether to the contract, that's what is in image 1.

Now for demo purpose I used my second account from remix, As you can see before I execute sendEther method my second account has 101 ether, After executing the sendEther method it increase to 102 and decrease 1 ether from my caller account. Now in this case my account 1 is `Person A` and my second account is `Person B`.

Comment: Can you explain in just a little more detail the screenshots? Otherwise, great answer.